# getProductCollection count after updating filters

Tags: magento2.3, product-collection

I wrote a little piece of code that shows me the amount of products in a category. However, after applying filters through one of the Amasty extensions, the count is incorrect and stays at the original.

```
<?= $helper->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection()->count(); ?>
```

That's how the count is shown. Below is the definition of `getCurrentCategory()`.

```
public function getCurrentCategory(){
    return $this->registry->registry('current_category');
}
```

Is there any way to update the count after a filter has been applied?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing the root issue you're trying to solve, but I don't believe the `getCurrentCategory()` takes into account applied filters. I'd expect you to get the results you're currently getting because the count of products in that category will never change when its being filtered. Filtering just narrows the number of products displayed. It doesn't decrease the number of products in the category.